# Checksum wiping out member since date!

Tags: civimember, webform-civicrm, checksum

We've starting using checksum in civimail for membership renewals. The checksum link takes the user to a webform in which they can renew.

When they do renew the membership is being recorded as a new membership wiping out the member since date.

For example, one person has been a member since 2010. Now it reads 2016.

Anyone know why this is happening.

Thanks,
Andy
CIVICRM 4.5.8
Drupal 7
We've updated webforms and webforms-civicrm to latest version

Comment: might need to add what version of wf and wf-civi you are on

Comment: thanks, we're using the latest version of those two modules

Answer (score 1):

I think this is nothing to do with the checksum (other than that causes the right contact to load) but is an issue with webform-civicrm overwriting existing info in the membership table.

Pretty sure this is an issue with the webform_civicrm code. Have raised [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2852365)